How to add a new method in IdentityErrorDescriber in AspNetCore.Identity
For identity I am using AspNetCore.Identity package in my project.
I am going to customize the register endpoint. The request body should be phone number and password.
In this case, it may return some error messages that is related to the phone number.
For example, PhoneNumber xxx is invalid, PhoneNumber xxx is duplicated, ...
So I am going to add some error describers by customizing IdentityErrorDescriber.
public class AuthErrorDescriber : IdentityErrorDescriber
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an <see cref="IdentityError"/> indicating the specified <paramref name="phoneNumber"/> is invalid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="phoneNumber">The phoneNumber that is invalid.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="IdentityError"/> indicating the specified <paramref name="phoneNumber"/> is invalid.</returns>
    public virtual IdentityError InvalidPhoneNumber(string? phoneNumber)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(InvalidPhoneNumber),
            // Here, I cannot customize or use `Resources`
            // for example `Resources.PasswordMismatch`
            Description = $"PhoneNumber '{phoneNumber}' is invalid."
        };
    }
}

I added the error describer like this.
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddErrorDescriber<AuthErrorDescriber>();

But I cannot use that new method in my code
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber) || !PhoneNumberHelper.IsValid(phoneNumber))
{
    return CreateValidationProblem(IdentityResult.Failed(userManager.ErrorDescriber.InvalidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)));
}

Here is the error I get:

CS1061: 'IdentityErrorDescriber' does not contain a definition for 'InvalidPhoneNumber' and no accessible extension method 'InvalidPhoneNumber' accepting a first argument of type 'IdentityErrorDescriber' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I resolve above issue? Any other approaches to add new methods there?

In order to extend existing class with new methods, you have at least 2 options:

inheritance (option of your choice) - allows adding new methods, overriding them, etc., but has drawback - if we don't control what calls our code, it might be that we can't change the base type to derived, we create (which is your problem) - in that case we will loose all new methods on our derived type,
extensions methods - they an be used to "add" methods to existing types - I think that one you will like :)

So, going with extensions methods, you can specify:
public static IdentityExtensions
{
    public static IdentityError InvalidPhoneNumber(this IdentityErrorDescriber errorDescriber, string? phoneNumber)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(InvalidPhoneNumber),
            // Here, I cannot customize or use `Resources`
            // for example `Resources.PasswordMismatch`
            Description = $"PhoneNumber '{phoneNumber}' is invalid."
        };
    }
}

You could try inspecting source code of IdentityErrorDescriber and see if you can override any virtual method, by I did not find and good candidate.

The reason why it shows this error is clearly, the custom AuthErrorDescriber you created is correctly registered in the Identity services, but when you try to access your custom method (InvalidPhoneNumber) using userManager.ErrorDescriber, it is treated as the base IdentityErrorDescriber type instead of your derived AuthErrorDescriber type.
To solve this error, I suggest you could try this code:
var errorDescriber = userManager.ErrorDescriber as AuthErrorDescriber;

if (errorDescriber != null)
{
    var result = IdentityResult.Failed(errorDescriber.InvalidPhoneNumber("phoneNumber"));
}

Result:

